# Is it possible to play a sound when a notification is received?

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

I'm investigating implementing push notifications in my solution, and I'd like to play an application-specific sound when I receive a notification.

I've been using the following sample as a guide: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/push-and-periodic-de225603

I've added `pushNotification` as a Background Task in the app manifest:

```
<Extensions>
  <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="PushNotificationsHelper.MaintenanceTask">
    <BackgroundTasks>
      <Task Type="systemEvent" />
      <Task Type="pushNotification"/>
    </BackgroundTasks>
  </Extension>
</Extensions>
```

and `MaintenanceTask` is defined as:

```
namespace PushNotificationsHelper
{
    public sealed class MaintenanceTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            Notifier notifier = new Notifier();
            notifier.RenewAllAsync(false).AsTask().Wait();

            // here I can execute my code to locate the sound in my solution and play it
        }
    }
}
```

It would be ideal for this Run method to execute and then let me play a sound.

However, I can't get the run method to fire when I'm testing with the Windows Phone emulator's Notification Tool.

What do I need to do to get this to run? Is there a different way for me to play sounds associated with my app?